# Do azure data factory supports escape characters?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to use newline escape character in azure data factory expressions. What is the right escape character for newline in data factory expressions?

Comment: Pipeline or data flow expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this isn't supported.

You can vote to get this feature in future releases in [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/36485140-newlines-in-dynamic-content) link

Comment: Hi @Pinaak : If my response helped you, can you please mark it as an answer so that we can have others from community to benefit from it :). Thanks !